# Camera going on it own?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've have using opengl 3 made a 3D camera, which works but has a jitter when looking around with mouse, I've tried reworking the system but just can't fix it. Below is the input function, I'm using. I've cut out some of the input getting to shorten this post.

**EDIT** I Think I stated my question wrongly, whats happening is that
the camera seems to just go off on its own, being hard to control. Their still is a jitter but having the camera just drift is what stumps me.

```
void Camera::GetInput()
{
int Screenx;
int Screeny;
glfwGetWindowSize(&Screenx, &Screeny);
static double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
float deltaTime = float(currentTime - lastTime);


int xpos, ypos;
glfwGetMousePos(&xpos, &ypos);
glfwSetMousePos(Screenx / 2, Screeny / 2);
// Compute new orientation
horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed * deltaTime * float(Screenx / 2 - xpos);
verticalAngle += mouseSpeed * deltaTime * float(Screeny / 2 - ypos);

glm::vec3 direction(
    cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle),
    sin(verticalAngle),
    cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle)
    );

glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(
    sin(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f),
    0,
    cos(horizontalAngle - 3.14f / 2.0f)
    );

glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, direction);

// Move forward
// Strafe left
if (glfwGetKey('A') == GLFW_PRESS){
    position -= right * deltaTime * speed;
}
float _fieldOfView(50.0f);
float _nearPlane(0.01f);
float _farPlane(1000.0f);
float _viewportAspectRatio(Screenx / Screeny);
ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(_fieldOfView, _viewportAspectRatio, _nearPlane, _farPlane);
ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    position,           // Camera is here
    position + direction, // and looks here : at the same position, plus "direction"
    up                  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you are calculation the delta properly? And please indent your code properly an keep your variable names consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut tells me that you are abusing the `static` storage qualifier here.

Since this is C++, `lastTime` will be initialized the first time you call `Camera::GetInput (...)` and that is the only time it is ever assigned a value. Generally, a variable called `deltaTime` is supposed to be the amount of time elapsed since the last camera update, not the time elapsed since the very first call to `Camera::GetInput (...)`.

Having a `static` variable at this scope in a class function feels wrong to me. If you have two instances of this class they will both use the value of `lastTime` that was established on the first call to `Camera::GetInput (...)`.

The fact that you are calling `glfwGetWindowSize(&Screenx, &Screeny);` from within this function implies to me that `Camera` is implicitly a singleton. Otherwise, those would be passed parameters or at least acquired in a less direct way.

#### Nevertheless, you still need to update the value of `lastTime` at the end of this function.

```
void Camera::GetInput()
{
  // [...]

  ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
      position,           // Camera is here
      position + direction, // and looks here : at the same position, plus "direction"
      up                  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
      );

  //
  // This will fix your problem
  //
  lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Comment: I just tryed it, didn't look to fix much :/